# How to avoid input modification in PDL subroutines

Tags: perl, pdl

I would like to avoid the assignment operator `.=` to modify the user input from a subroutine.

One way to avoid this is to perform a copy of the input inside the subroutine. Is this the best way to proceed? Are there other solutions?

```perl
use PDL;use strict;
my $a=pdl(1);
f_0($a);print "$a\n";
f_1($a);print "$a\n";
sub f_0{
    my($input)=@_;
    my $x=$input->copy;
    $x.=0;
}
sub f_1{
    my($input)=@_;
    $input.=0;
}
```

In my case (perl 5.22.1), executing last script prints `1` and `0` in two lines. `f_0` does not modify user input in-place, while `f_1` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FAQ [6.17 What happens when I have several references to the same PDL object in different variables](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::FAQ#Q:-6.17-What-happens-when-I-have-several-references-to-the-same-PDL-object-in-different-variables-(cloning,-etc?)-?) :

> Piddles behave like Perl references in many respects. So when you say
>
> ```
> $a = pdl [0,1,2,3]; $b = $a;
> ```
>
> then both `$b` and `$a` point to the same
>   object, e.g. then saying
>
> ```
> $b++;
> ```
>
> will *not* create a copy of the original piddle but just
>   increment in place
>   [...]
>   It is important to keep the "reference nature" of piddles in mind when
>   passing piddles into subroutines. If you modify the input piddles you
>   modify the original argument, not a copy of it. This is different from
>   some other array processing languages but makes for very efficient
>   passing of piddles between subroutines. If you do not want to modify
>   the original argument but rather a copy of it just create a copy
>   explicitly...

So yes, to avoid modification of the original, create a copy as you did:

```
my $x = $input->copy;
```

or alternatively:

```
my $x = pdl( $input );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must comment, however, that the sentence "...If you modify the input piddles you modify the original argument, not a copy of it..." is a bit misleading: if in the f_1 subroutine you replace '.=' by '=', then the user input is not modified at all. The assignment operator '.=', which is a PDL thing I think, is important in reproducing this behavior.